# PHP Spatie DTOs with sub arrays

Tags: php, rest, dto, data-transfer-objects

I'm trying to implement an endpoint for the [Audd audio detection API](https://docs.audd.io/streams/) (callback with a result), using [Spatie's Data Transfer Object package](https://packagist.org/packages/spatie/data-transfer-object) for PHP. For this, I have a `PlayDTO`, which has a `PlayResultDTO` attribute, which in turn should have an array of `PlayTrackDTO`s as a sub-attribute:

```
// PlayDTO.php
namespace App\DTO\Play;
use Spatie\DataTransferObject\DataTransferObject;

class PlayDTO extends DataTransferObject
{
    public string $status;
    public PlayResultDTO $result;
}

//PlayResultDTO.php
namespace App\DTO\Play;
use Spatie\DataTransferObject\DataTransferObject;
class PlayResultDTO extends DataTransferObject
{
    public int $radio_id;
    public string $timestamp;
    public int $play_length;
    /** @var PlayTrackDTO[] */
    #[CastWith(ArrayCaster::class, itemType: PlayTrackDTO::class)]
    public array $results;
}

// PlayTrackDTO.php
namespace App\DTO\Play;
use Spatie\DataTransferObject\DataTransferObject;
class PlayTrackDTO extends DataTransferObject
{
    public string $artist;
    public string $title;
    public string $album;
    public string $release_date;
    public string $label;
    public int $score;
    public string $song_link;
}
```

When I pass a valid array of data to my `PlayDTO` constructor, in the newly instaitated `PlayDTO` class, `$result` correctly has type `PlayResultDTO`, but in that `$result` it's `$results` attribute is just a simple array of keyed-arrays, when it should be an array of `PlayTrackDTO` objects.

As far as I can see I followed the guide correctly. I have the most up to date version of the package installed, as well as using PHP8. Would anyone have any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Did you find the solution?

I see that your question is about PHP 8. Still, I am wondering, if one can solve the same problem using PHP 7.4? There, I cannot even use `#[CastWith...]`, and putting type hints in a phpdoc, e.g. `/** @var PlayTrackDTO[] */`, does not seem to be enough.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the CastWith class form Spatie Attributes.
Also, you are using ArrayCaster, so you need to use that as well.

```
use Spatie\DataTransferObject\Casters\ArrayCaster;
use Spatie\DataTransferObject\Attributes\CastWith;
```